# Next item, nextButton,

Tags: android, listview

I have an Activity (MainWordsActivity) that has a ListView populated by data from database, when one of its items is clicked I pass that row of database and its position on the ListView to another activity (DetailActivity). I also have a next button in the DetailActivity, each time it is clicked, I want the next item in the ListView to show up on the same activity and view.  what I want is to display the next item on Listview after the nextButton is clicked.
How can I have access to the next item, or is it possible achieving this purpose by using Cursor. 
thanks

MainWordsActivity

```
private ArrayList<Word> testing;
 @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

        ArrayList<Word> result = new ArrayList<Word>();

        Word word = testing.get(position);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);

        Bundle extras = new Bundle();
        extras.putInt("pos", position);

        extras.putParcelable(".model.Word", word);
        intent.putExtras(extras);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

DetailActivity

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.word_detail);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
         pos = extras.getInt("pos");

        word = extras.getParcelable(".model.Word");

        refreshDisplay();
enter code here
        Button butNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBut);

        butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                pos ++;


        ???

}

});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this is to pass the Array of `Word` objects as well as the `pos` to the `DetailActivity`.

Since `Word` is a `Parcelable` object, you can use `putParcelableArrayList()` to put the entire `testing` `ArrayList` in the `Bundle`. Try this:

**MainWordsActivity**:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetailActivity.class);

    Bundle extras = new Bundle();
    extras.putInt("pos", position);
    extras.putParcelableArrayList(".model.Word", testing);

    intent.putExtras(extras);

    startActivity(intent);

}
```

And in your **DetailActivity**:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.word_detail);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    pos = extras.getInt("pos");

    ArrayList<Word> words = extras.getParcelableArrayList(".model.Word");
    word = words.get(pos);

    refreshDisplay();

    Button butNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextBut);
    butNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            pos++;
            word = words.get(pos); // get the next word from the list

            refreshDisplay(); // I am assuming this updates the UI
            /* ANY OTHER UI CHANGES CAN GO HERE */
        }
    });
}
```

This should achieve what you want. I am assuming that `refreshDisplay()` will update the UI, but if not that is where you would update the UI based on the new `word`. You should also check to make sure you do not go out of bounds on your `ArrayList`, etc.

Furthermore, I removed this line:

`ArrayList<Word> result = new ArrayList<Word>();`

from your `MainWordsActivity` since you did not seem to be using it at all.

Comment: @M.mirzaie glad I could help!